# Base64Transcoder.m duplicate symbols

Tags: ios, xcode

I would like to use the SKPSMTPMessage library. the only thing is that this library contains the file Base64Transcoder.m, which since I have the Dropbox SDK is giving a duplicate error. how can I solve this error? 
I can't just delete the Base64Transcoder.m file because it is being imported in the SKPSMTPMessage library.

Thanks for any help

Comment: @SibaPrasadHota: please don't vote to close an older question as a duplicate of a newer question.  Otherwise, this runs the risk of both questions getting closed.  In the past, questioners who have had two questions closed as duplicates of each other have sometimes responded by asking another duplicate question.