# import a file in a framework xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Base64Transcoder.m duplicate symbols](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13540610/base64transcoder-m-duplicate-symbols)

I would like to use the SKPSMTPMessage library. The only thing is that this library contains the file Base64Transcoder.m, which is contained even in the Dropbox SDK. Therefore I am having a duplicate error. I can't just delete the Base64Transcoder.m file because it is being imported in the SKPSMTPMessage library. 
I tried importing instead of the file the dropbox SDK but it doesn't work. is there a way to import just a file in the SDK?

Thanks for any help

Comment: sorry but I wanted to change the title

Comment: @Alessandro: if you want to change the title, go back to your original question and edit it.